# How to toggle letter casing in text provided by the user??

Tags: delphi

How to toggle case?

Firstly, get a sentence from the user written in a `TEdit` box,
eg

> The fastest animal is a cheetah

Then toggle the case and display it in a `TPanel`, eg:

> ThE FaStEsT AnImAl Is A ChEeTaH

Comment: The first step is to find and read a good book about programming in general and Delphi programming in particular. Once you've finished reading that book, you can probably solve tasks such as this one easily.

Comment: (Also, FWIW: Your example doesn't *toggle* the case.)

Answer (score 1):

The normal way would be to iterate over the string, alternating uppercasing and lowercasing the characters, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Character;

var
  str, result: String;
  i: Integer;
  ch: Char;
begin
  str := ...;
  i := 0;
  for ch in str do
  begin
    if not Odd(i) then
      result := result + ch.ToUpper
    else
      result := result + ch.ToLower;
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Character;

var
  str: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  str := ...;
  for i := 1 to Length(str) do
  begin
    if Odd(i) then
      str[i] := str[i].ToUpper
    else
      str[i] := str[i].ToLower;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Remy: Not a fan of the `Odd` function?

Comment: Also, `TCharacter.ToUpper` is deprecated. You should do `ch.ToUpper`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand honestly, I keep forgetting that `Odd()` exists, as I never use it in my own code

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That happens to me too sometimes (for other functions).